# Identify the number of unique values and then the number of occurrences of those values in the file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have a data file which contains 15000 lines, but only 400 unique values. I am looking for a way to identify the number of unique values and then the number of occurrences of those values in the file. I came up with the following but it is very very slow. Any thoughts?

```
for value in `cat mylist.txt | uniq`
do
    counter=`grep $value mylist.txt |wc -l`
    echo $value $counter
done
```

Comment: Don't do `cat file | uniq`; like most Unix text utilities, uniq can take a filename as an argument for input

Comment: @itsbruce: True, but you still need to sort before passing to uniq. `sort file | uniq` is better.

Comment: I'm not disputing that at all; just picking up on a particular style problem of the originally posted code.  **cat**'s primary purpose is for concatenating *multiple* inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use sort and uniq:

```
sort mylist.txt | uniq | wc -l
```

That will give you the number of unique values. To get the number of occurrences of each unique value, use `uniq`'s -c option:

```
sort mylist.txt | uniq -c
```

From the `uniq` man page:

```
   -c, --count
               prefix lines by the number of occurrences
```

Also, for future reference, `grep`'s -c option is often useful:

```
 -c, --count
              Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print  a  count  of
              matching  lines  for  each  input  file.   With the -v,
              --invert-match option (see below),  count  non-matching
              lines.  (-c is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Thank you terdon... "sort mylist.txt | uniq -c" was exactly what I needed.

Comment: FYI "sort -u mylist.txt" is the same as "sort mylist.txt | uniq" but works slightly faster.

Comment: @citrin yes, but that's a GNU feature, so not portable.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one.

```
for w in `cat $file`; 
do 
    echo $w; 
done|sort|uniq -c
```

Comment: @thrig: Do you get notified of this ping? If you look closely, you'll see that this answer, although terrible, worked (pretty much) as posted, and Tomas's edit (which you approved) changed the code so it would no longer work. Some suggested edits should be rejected (or, at least, improved upon).